# Reading keyboard state in ocamlsdl

Tags: ocaml, sdl

I'm trying to learn how to use the SDL libraries with OCaml, but I'm running into problems with handling keyboard input.

Specifically, I'm trying to understand how to use Sdlkey.get_key_state, which has a signature like this:

```
val get_key_state : unit ->
   (int, Bigarray.int8_unsigned_elt, Bigarray.c_layout) Bigarray.Array1.t
```

Essentially, I want to use the method outlined in this [lazy foo tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson10/index.php). In C, it would look like this:

```
Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState( NULL );

//If up is pressed
if( keystates[ SDLK_UP ] )
{
    printf( "Up was pressed" );
}
```

Using the keystate array, you can check to see if each relevant key is being pressed. The alternate way of doing this is to poll for a key press event, and in OCaml it can be identified using pattern matching, for example:

```
let handleEvent ev = 
    match ev with
    | Sdlevent.KEYDOWN {Sdlevent.keysym=Sdlkey.KEY_ESCAPE} -> exit 0
    | _ -> ()

let mainLoop () = 
    while true do
        begin match Sdlevent.poll () with
        | None -> ()
        | Some ev -> handleEvent ev
        end;
    done
```

I've seen several examples that illustrate this method, but I can't find any information on how to read the values returned from Sdlkey.get_key_state. I'm fairly new to functional programming, so this is a bit over my head. Can someone show me how to rewrite the C code above in OCaml?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know ocamlsdl (though I've used SDL before). But it might be good enough just to point out that OCaml big arrays are like C arrays, there's nothing particularly "functional" about them.

The nomenclature for the Bigarray module is quite thick, but what you're seeing is that `get_key_state` returns a one-dimensional array of unsigned 8-bit values, laid out the way that C lays out arrays. You can access an array element with the (not particularly pretty) notation `a.{index}`.

So the OCaml equivalent might look like this:

```
let keystates = get_key_state () in
if keystates.{KEY_UP} <> 0 then
    (* Up key was pressed *)
```

One thing missing here is that I don't know exactly how to get the index `KEY_UP`. But it's probably explained in the docs for ocamlsdl.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it up for me. Also, the int_of_key function casts it to the appropriate index. `keystates.{ int_of_key KEY_UP }`